# How to add a display format for the field

Tags: 8, entities

I have a field of list type in my custom content type. The display format of list type field has two options default(value) and key.  In my case i want third option which will display "key and value". How can i add third option or get the key/value for the field.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how to create custom field formatters

https://github.com/npinos/drupal8-field-formatters

You can directly specify the markup like this extending the FormatterBase class:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains Drupal\drupal8_field_formatters\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\MainHeadingFormatter.
 */
namespace Drupal\drupal8_field_formatters\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FormatterBase;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'main_heading_formatter' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "main_heading_formatter",
 *   label = @Translation("Heading 1"),
 *   weight = "10",
 *   field_types = {
 *     "string",
 *     "text",
 *   },
 *   quickedit = {
 *     "editor" = "plain_text"
 *   }
 * )
 */
class MainHeadingFormatter extends FormatterBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $element = [];
    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      // Render each element as markup.
      $element[$delta] = [
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => '<h1>' . $item->value . '</h1>',
      ];
    }
    return $element;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will require to write your own custom field formatter to achieve that. There are detailed docs at : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-field-formatter

File /modules/custom_module/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/KeyValueFormatter.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_module\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FormatterBase;
use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'key_value' formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "key_value_list",
 *   label = @Translation("Key - value"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "list_string"
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

The `field_types` key determines the type of the field this formatter will be available to. Just override the `viewElements` function in the `KeyValueFormatter` class and let them display key - value.

I would recommend extending `Drupal\options\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\OptionsDefaultFormatter` instead of `FormatterBase` as suggested by the docs.

Comment: Drupal\options\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\OptionsDefaultFormatter also extending FormatterBase . Good thing will be  i will have secure code and won't have to include 'use Drupal\Core\Field\AllowedTagsXssTrait;' and other namespaces. You do make sense on the above.  Docs are for generic formatter.

Comment: @AdityaJoshi On the contrary, the AllowedTagsXssTrait helps you prevent the XSS vulnerabilities by filtering any HTML that might be a part of the field settings.